# Summary op crashes when run multiple times

Tags: python, tensorflow

Opening a session for the second time and trying to run a summary op causes crash for some reason. The error message is misleading as a placeholder is clearly provided.

I am trying to test the same model on multiple datasets. So, I wanted to just reset the variables and create a new logdir for each dataset. Running them manually without a loop does the job but it is very tedious.

I tried notifying the tensorflow devs but they seemed to just ignore it. Is there a work around?

```
import tensorflow as tf

class MyModel:
    def __init__(self, sess, i):
        self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [2, 2])
        self.W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2, 2]))
        self.y = tf.matmul(self.W, self.x)

        tf.summary.scalar('y',tf.reduce_sum(self.y))

        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        self.summary = tf.summary.merge_all()
        self.writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./logs/test' + str(i),sess.graph)

    def run(self, sess):        
        feed_dict = {self.x:[[0,0],[0,0]]}
        sess.run(self.y,feed_dict)
        print('inside1')
        s = sess.run(self.summary,feed_dict)
        print('inside2')
        self.writer.add_summary(s,0)

    def close(self):
        self.writer.close()        

# Swapping order of line 1 and 2 still causes crash
for i in range(3): # line 1
    with tf.Session() as sess: # line 2
        print('outside')
        M = MyModel(sess, i)
        M.run(sess)
        M.close()
    #sess.close() # No luck
```

## Output

```
outside
inside1
inside2
outside
inside1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1323, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1302, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [2,2]
     [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[2,2], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
     [[Node: Sum_1/_7 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_7_Sum_1", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\TensorFlow\tensorflow-experiments\ravens-matrix-autoencoder\minimum.py", line 31, in <module>
    M.run(sess)
  File "D:\TensorFlow\tensorflow-experiments\ravens-matrix-autoencoder\minimum.py", line 20, in run
    s = sess.run(self.summary,feed_dict)
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 889, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1120, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1317, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1336, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [2,2]
     [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[2,2], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
     [[Node: Sum_1/_7 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_7_Sum_1", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'Placeholder', defined at:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 124, in main
    ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 351, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "D:\TensorFlow\tensorflow-experiments\ravens-matrix-autoencoder\minimum.py", line 30, in <module>
    M = MyModel(sess, i)
  File "D:\TensorFlow\tensorflow-experiments\ravens-matrix-autoencoder\minimum.py", line 5, in __init__
    self.x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [2, 2])
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 1599, in placeholder
    return gen_array_ops._placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 3090, in _placeholder
    "Placeholder", dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2956, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1470, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [2,2]
     [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[2,2], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
     [[Node: Sum_1/_7 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_7_Sum_1", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `tf.reset_default_graph()` before `with Session() as sess:` fixed the problem. Tensorflow tries to use the placeholder of the last graph instead of the current graph.